# Click, hold and drag to the left in Protractor

Tags: protractor

For my site, I want to click, hold and drag to the left an element, so it appears a trash icon.

I don't want to drag to a specific position, *but just drag to the left*, so I tried to decrease X value, also this does not work.

The following code below passes but does nothing.

```js
 it('should delete unexpected item', function(){
        let el = element(by.css("div[fxlayout='row']"));

        el.getLocation().then(function (location) {
            console.log(location.y);
            console.log(location.x);

        });
       
        browser.actions().mouseDown(el).perform();
        browser.sleep(3000);
        browser.actions().mouseMove({ x: 30, y: 0 }).perform();
        browser.actions().mouseDown(el).perform();
        browser.actions().mouseMove({ x: 10, y: 0 }).perform();
        browser.actions().mouseUp().perform();
        browser.sleep(3000);


    })
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to just move to the sides.

```
it('should delete unexpected item', function(){
        let el = element(by.css("div[class='delete-indicator']"));

        el.getLocation().then(function (location) {
            console.log(location.y);
            console.log(location.x);

        });

        browser.actions().mouseDown(el).perform();
        browser.sleep(1000);
        browser.actions().mouseMove({ x: 293, y: 0 }).perform(); ///start position
        browser.actions().mouseDown(el).perform();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        browser.actions().mouseMove({ x: -90, y: 0 }).perform(); ///final position

        browser.actions().mouseUp().perform();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.css('.delete-icon')).click();
        browser.sleep(3000);        

    })
```